# Removing a span with a specific class from HTML , but not the content using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Here is the sample html

```
<div>
<span class="target"> Remove  parent span class only and save this text </span>      
</div>
```

Here I want above html as following using regex function only

```
<div>
Remove parent span class only and save this text
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<h3 class="target>(.*?)</h3>#', '', $html);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: $html = preg_replace('#<h3 class="target>(.*?)</h3>#', '', $html), but it completely replaces its content.

Comment: ^ Then [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29945540/edit) this into your question and show your effort/work!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, But that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching wrong tag, h3 instead of span
Also check signature of the preg_replace, 2nd argument is replacement, in your case it is empty string.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<(span)[^\>]+>(.*?)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $html);
```

Edit:
Just noticed that op wanted to remove only spans with specific class

```
$html = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?target(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $html);
```

This should cover spans with any number of attributes and classes and replace those spans that has class target.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
$html = preg_replace('#<(\w+) class="target">(.*)<\/\1>#', '\2', $html);
```

Explanations :

`<` matches the characters `<` literally

1st Capturing group `(\w+)`

- `\w+` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` this way, you can capture any tag (h3, span etc).
- Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  `class="target">` matches the characters  `class="target">` literally (case sensitive)

2nd Capturing group `(.*)` matches any character

`<` matches the characters `<` literally

`\/` matches the character `/` literally

`\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

`>` matches the characters `>` literally

The `\2` means that it will replace with the 2nd Capturing group.

PS : Using regex with HTML can lead to unexpected results, be careful if you use it (for example, in this case, you can break the regex by adding another class or attribute to the tag).

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: EDIT : added precisions

Comment: Thanks very very much, You made my day very easy.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this question as resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to understand but using jquery you can try something like that :

```
$('#target').parent().append($('#target').text());
$('#target').remove();
```

Comment: But the OP wants a solution with regex.